# How can I have different CSS when I print or print preview?

Tags: css

I'd like to change some things on my web page. Also I would like to make some things hidden. Is there a way I can do this with CSS when I print? In particular I want to be able to hide some DIVs and all that they contain.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This can be achieved with a separate print stylesheet. The `media` attribute is the key:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I hide a DIV from view? Is there a way to do that also?

Comment: @MIMI: Do it in the print stylesheet with `display: none`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @MIMI Yes, just target the `div` in the print stylesheet and set it to `display: none`. Ie. `#myDiv { display: none; }`. Edit: BoltClock was faster. =)

Comment: You should be able to apply all styles the same as you would for the actual webpage (media is screen for the browser).

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you need to use the `media` attribute when you include your css. E.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my_print_style.css" media="print">
```

Or, you can use the media rule in your stylesheets if for example, you do not have enough changes to warrant a whole new stylesheet. Something like this,

```
@media print {
    // print specific styles.
}
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule, for details and valid media types.

Answer (score 7):

Answer is the CSS @media rule: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule

Answer (score 2):

I've used

```
<link href="print.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```

To achieve this. Assign #ids or .classes to elements you don't want to display. And use *display: none* for those elements in print.css stylesheet.

Comment: If you want to maintain spacing by removing specific elements without losing its spacing, use `visibility: hidden` instead.